# ubuntu - when try to install solana - get error

Tags: linux, command, ubuntu-16.04, blockchain, solana

I am trying to install Solana:

> sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.7.12/install)"

I am getting:
downloading v1.7.12 installer

> > > /tmp/tmp.uKtHJnlk2o/solana-install-init: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

please help me

Answer (score 0):

maybe `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get install openssl` can help.

```
root@53794cb0b15a:/# apt info libssl1.1
Package: libssl1.1
Version: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8
Priority: important
Section: libs
Source: openssl
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Homepage: https://www.openssl.org/
[...]
Packages
**Description: Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries**
```

Comment: thanks for replying
i have an old version, because when typing openssl version, i got OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
ubuntu@ubuntu-vbox:/usr/local/openssl-1.1.0l$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl

Comment: Your distribution may be too old, but as the answerer mentioned you can try to install version 1.1 using `apt-get install libssl1.1`